# Word subscripts in latex

Tags: math-mode, formatting, subscripts

I am trying to make a formula like below image:

[image]

As you see a word like **parent** is subscripted to the **pro**

so what i have tried is:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}



\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}


    〖pro〗_parent=〖Mainpro〗_parent*(1-〖pro〗_child)


\end{document}
```

But the output is not what i want?

Comment: `\[\mathrm{pro}_\mathrm{parent} = ...\]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pick up an introductory book on LaTeX and study math mode.  Inline math is delimited by `$...$` or `\(...\)`, and display math is delimited by `\[...\]` (unnumbered) or, for example, `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` (numbered).

The text form of math can be achieved by `\textrm` or, depending on the circumstance, `\mathrm`.  However, `\textrm` in a subscript will not take on the smaller size (unless `amsmath` is also loaded [thanks, Gustavo]). Generally, the whole subscript should be enclosed in braces so that TeX understands its full extent, though in this case, the `\mathrm` accomplishes as much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Inline is $\mathrm{pro}_\mathrm{parent} = \mathrm{Mainpro}_\mathrm{parent} 
  \times (1 - \mathrm{pro}_\mathrm{child})$. Blah, blah.  In an equation is
  given by
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{pro}_\mathrm{parent} = \mathrm{Mainpro}_\mathrm{parent} 
  \times (1 - \mathrm{pro}_\mathrm{child})
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `amsmath` package, one might use `\text` in preference to `\mathrm` or `\textrm`.  However, as Barbara points out, that could cause grief inside of italic environments like theorems.

Comment: with `amsmath`, the `\text` style will follow the style of the surrounding text, so within a theorem it would become (text) italic.  so `\texrm` really is the better choice if these words should always be upright.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Except in a subscript, `\textrm` does not shrink.

Comment: good point.  in that case, `\text{\upshape ...}` would be what's needed.

Comment: (To Steven B. Seglets and) @barbarabeeton: When the `amsmath` package is loaded, `\textrm` (as well as `\textup`) *does* typeset subscripts in `\scriptsize`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti -- oh, dear, i really should know that!  (i'm afraid my brain has just been stuffed too full of other things.)  thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you do not want to use math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mysubscript}[1]{\raisebox{-0.34ex}{\scriptsize#1}}

pro\mysubscript{parent} = Mainpro\mysubscript{parent} $\times$ (1 $-$     
                          pro\mysubscript{child})


\end{document}
```

[image]